# NSURLConnection won't respond after I get Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=57

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, websocket, socket.io

So here's the brief description of the issue:

I have an app that uses web sockets SocketRocket - client-side, Nodejs + Socket.io - server side.
 I establish a socket connection upon launch of the application and everything works just fine. In case i suspend the app (going to background, locking screen, etc) I'm able to reconnect upon entering foreground.
 However if i lose connection (for example, if i block myself on the router (i get a socket failure error in 5-10 seconds), then unblock myself) - i won't be able to connect to ANY url with `NSURLConnection`. (Why am I bothering with this? Well, people tend to loose often on mobile devices, so I have to handle this error)

This code is getting called upon connectivity restore/entering foreground if i previously had a working connection.

```
 -(void) connectToHost:(NSString *)host onPort:(NSInteger)port withParams:(NSDictionary*)params withNamespace:(NSString *)endpoint
{    

  if (!_isConnected && !_isConnecting) 
  {
    _isConnecting = YES;

    _host = host;
    _port = port;
    _endpoint = [endpoint copy];

    NSMutableString *query = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    [params enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id key, id value, BOOL *stop) {
        [query appendFormat:@"&%@=%@",key,value];
    }];

    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:HANDSHAKE_URL, _host, _port, rand(), query];
    [self log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connecting to socket with URL: %@",s]];        

    _timeout = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(disconnect) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    [[LRResty client] get:s withBlock:^(LRRestyResponse *response) {
        [_timeout invalidate], _timeout = nil;                                
        if ( response.status == 200 )
        {
            NSString *responseString = [response asString];

            [self log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"requestFinished() %@", responseString]];
            NSArray *data = [responseString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

            _sid = [data objectAtIndex:0];
            [self log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sid: %@", _sid]];

            _heartbeatTimeout = [[data objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] + 7.0;
            [self log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"heartbeatTimeout: %f", _heartbeatTimeout]];

            NSString *t = [data objectAtIndex:3];
            NSArray *transports = [t componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
            [self log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"transports: %@", transports]];

            [self openSocket];                 
        }
        else
        {
            [_delegate socketIOHandshakeFailed:self];
        }
    }];                       
  }                 
}
```

That's what i get in a normal case:

```
Connecting to socket with URL: https://example.com:9001/socket.io/1/?t=282442 
requestFinished() ==> 843717395328441553:60:60:websocket
debug: Finished request GET https://example.com:9001/socket.io/1/?t=282442 <LRRestyRequest>
```

In case i try to reconnect after connection failure:

```
Connecting to socket with URL: https://example.com:9001/socket.io/1/?t=282475249
```

I tried running a synchronous request, yet it would block my UI and will never finish. So, actually request is probably trying to start, but never gets to the point of execution.

This is what i get if i pause an app in the debugger:
 you can see the screenshot here -> http://avvs.co/static/app_paused.jpg
Check thread 7 -

```
#0 0x9855fc22 in mach_msg_trap ()
#7 0x026852d3 in -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] ()
#8 0x00019b1b in -[LRURLRequestOperation start]
#9 0x00016670 in -[LRRestyRequest start]
```

**UPDATE**
this  is the complete operations list for this thread, would be really glad if you can point out what's wrong in here

```
#0  0x9855fc22 in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x9855f1f6 in mach_msg ()
#2  0x0073c10a in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
#3  0x0069f5d5 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#4  0x0069ed84 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#5  0x0069ec9b in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#6  0x0268540f in -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] ()
#7  0x026852d3 in -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] ()
#8  0x00019b0b in -[LRURLRequestOperation start]
#9  0x00016660 in -[LRRestyRequest start]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found the solution. Actual problem was not in the NSURLConnection, but in the socket implementation. When loosing connection, app was closing input and output streams, but  they were not removed from the running loop, nor were they dispatched. By fixing it I was able to restore connectivity.

Comment: could you please elaborate with some code samples if you can on how you fixed the issue? I have the same issue using the SocketRocket library. Once I remove the lan cable, the app tries reconnect but it never succeeds.

Comment: Hi Vitaly, Can you elaborate more on how to fix in the XMPP code if any. I am facing the same issue.